# Custom abbreviated date sequence in MS word doc

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, date-format

This is a weird one that I would be grateful for a solution from some clever person with time to play with word macros or suchlike.

I have a word (2007) document with a few consecutive dates in sequential order scattered within it.

I need this specific customised date stamp format like these:

```
Sa 18/3/23
Su 19/3/23
M 20/3/23
Tu 21/3/23
W 22/3/23
Th 23/3/23
F 24/3/23
```

Note the day name is abbreviated to one letter *when that's unambiguous* (eg F can only mean friday) and to 2 letters otherwise (S could be saturday or sunday so I use Sa and Su).

I'm really dumb as - I currently manually type in these dates each time I want to print some more sheets for the coming week.  I have to go through changing a bunch of sequential dates in places that it's really tedious to find.

**Please** Can someone show me how I can just set the first date manually so that the rest will automatically be consecutive AND display using the weird short format I use?

I'll try to attach the actually document, if I can figure out how to.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: With your special date format, you would be looking at a monstrosity like [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjzcqc2sloxr22j/deleteme%20Sequential%20Dates.docx?dl=0). Are you that adventurous?

Comment: I wrote the document that harrymc linked and yours will be even worse. There is NO field switch that will give you the abbreviations you want. The closest I know of will give the first three letters: ` \@ "ddd dd/MM/yy"` See Paul Edstein's Date Calculation Tutorial. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html. This would, I think, be much simpler in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Using complex field codes isn't ideal, particularly because the way field codes work, it is rather easy to lose the results of multiple calculations that re-use the same variable names when you save, close and re-open the document.

Personally I would probably aim for a solution that relied on some VBA and some content controls.

But if you aren't in a position to use VBA, try this:

Put the following field codes in your document header (or somewhere else where you won't damage them accidentally) and update them:

```
{SET SAT "Sa "}{SET SUN "Su "}{SET MON "Mo "}{SET TUE "Tu"}{SET WED "W "}{SET THU "Th "}{SET FRI "F "}
```

Then define the date *before* the date you want to start with like this:

```
{SET Y 2023}{SET M 3}{SET D 20}
```

Then, for each date, insert the following nested fields

```
{ SEQ C \h}{SET D{=D+1}}{SET "XDATE{SEQ C \c}" "{=Y}-{=M}-{=D}"}{SET E{={"XDATE{SEQ C \c}" \@YYYY}<Y}}{SET Y{=Y+(E*(M=12))}}{SET M{=IF(E,IF(M=12,1,M+1),M)}}{SET D{=IF(E,1,D)}}{SET "XDATE{SEQ C \c}" "{=Y}-{=M}-{=D}"}{REF {"XDATE{SEQ C \c}" \@DDD}}{"XDATE{SEQ C \c}" \@D/M/YY}
```

Make sure *all* the `{}` are the special field code brace pairs that you can enter using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word. (There are variations of these kestrokes for Mac Word and for different keyboards).

Then use ctrl-A to select your document and update all the fields. *Always* make sure you update *all* these fields together.

We use a SEQ field to create seven consecutive dates stored in bookmarks named XDATE1, XDATE2,..,XDATE7

The calculation relies on the fact that if XDATE1 (say) is a valid date, then the `\@YYYY` format option returns the date part of the year, but if it is not a valid date (e.g. suppose you set it to "2023-2-29" or "2023-12-32") then the `\@YYYY` format option has no effect and the whole string "2023-2-29" is returned, so it won't equal the value in Y, i.e. 2023. (In fact 2023-2-29 is treated as an arithmetic expression here, resul 1992, i.e. less than Y)

{REF {DT @DDD}} picks up the 3-letter day of the week abbreviation, e.g. WED for Wednesday, so that gives us {REF WED}, and because of our earlier {SET WED "W "} that inserts the abbreviation you want. You could use exactly that approach with the "macropod" fields mentioned by others if you prefer.